# Zimbra: How To Change The Active MTA Seever In a Multiserver Installation?

Tags: zimbra

**How can I change the active MTA server in a zimbra multiserver installation?**

I have a Zimbra 8.0.3 multiserver system with three instances: **b**, **c** and **d**. These servers have their own mailbox, MTA and LDAP servers. They are on a split domain where zimbra is the secondary domain.

Recently I added a new zimbra server **e** to the poll, which only has a MTA server. I want to disable the MTAs in b, c, and d and make them use the one in **e**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the zimbraSmtpHostname value is configured at the Server level. It can also be configured at the GlobalConfig or Domain level. To view your currently configured MTAs:

```
zmprov gcf zimbraSmtpHostname
zmproc gs `zmhostname` zimbraSmtpHostname   # do this on each mailstore server
zmprov gd example.com zimbraSmtpHostname      # do this for each active domain
```

To configure redundantly, additional MTAs must be added to the list. For example, at the Server level:

```
# su - zimbra
$ zmprov ms `zmhostname` +zimbraSmtpHostname mta1.example.com
$ zmprov ms `zmhostname` +zimbraSmtpHostname mta2.example.com
$ zmprov ms `zmhostname` +zimbraSmtpHostname mta3.example.com
```

or at the GlobalConfig level (since the Server level will override the GlobalConfig level, the Server level should be empty in order to use the GlobalConfig):

```
# su - zimbra
$ zmprov mcf +zimbraSmtpHostname mta1.example.com
$ zmprov mcf +zimbraSmtpHostname mta2.example.com
$ zmprov mcf +zimbraSmtpHostname mta3.example.com
```

And to disable MTAs do this:

```
zmprov ms server1 -zimbraServiceEnabled mta -zimbraServiceEnabled antispam -zimbraServiceEnabled antivirus
```